# CakePHP directory not found in Digitalocean

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have a create a blog in local, everything is working fine in local. After upload in digitalocean server I am not getting others page without home page.

This is the location : http://IP:8090/cake-blog/

If I try
http://IP:8090/cake-blog/articles
getting Not Found.

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf I have change none to all like below

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

listen 8090
<VirtualHost *:8090>
       ServerName 111.1**.1**.31
       DocumentRoot /var/www/wb02/
       <Directory /var/www/web02/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All extension I have enable. What could be problem now ?

Can anybody has idea ?

Comment: Your URL rewriting (`mod_rewrite`) isn't working (properly), as is apparent from the missing styling.

Comment: After enable mod_rewrite it's working fine now ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enable rewrite , my application working fine. I have applied below procedure.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```